# Copying documents from one collection to another in cloud firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Since there is no 'move' or 'rename' command in cloud firestore, I am trying to copy all documents from one collection to another every day at 6am (UK time). I have come up with this code upto now but not sure how I get the **resID** and then delete the original document once it is saved in another collection:

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 6 * * *')
    .timeZone('Europe/London') // Is this correct?
    .onRun((context) => {
    var dateObj = new Date();
    var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
    var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
    var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
    console.log(`This function ran at ${Date.now}!`);
    db.collection("Restaurants/${**resID**}/openorders").get().then(query => {
       query.forEach(function(doc) {
          var promise = firestore.collection("Restaurants/${**resID**}/closed/${year}/${month}/${day}/closed).doc(doc.data().orderID).set(doc.data());
// How I delete this document here?
       });
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log('Failure:', e);
        console.log(`This function ran with ERROR at ${Date.now}!`);
      });
    return null;
  });
```

Comment: Are you looking for `doc.ref.delete()`?

Comment: You want to transfer all your daily documents to another collection ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen maybe he is looking for how to get `resId`

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am looking on how to iterate between many redIDs. I tried to make it BOLD hence the astricks around them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over all collections named `openorders`, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

To then get the parent document of each `openorders` document, you can use the `ref` and `parent` properties.

So something like:

```
db.collectionGrouo("openorders").get().then(query => {
   query.forEach(function(doc) {
      let resID = doc.ref.parent.parent.id;
      ...
   });
})
```

For this type of thing I always recommend keeping the reference documentation handy, in this starting with [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot).

Comment: This is fantastic. Removed my solution as this is a far better method of handling the issue. I had no idea you could call the parent property of a DocumentReference and a CollectionReference. Literallly game-changing for me.

Comment: Good to hear @KasualDev    Navigating up the parent chain is a bit confusing at times (I end up counting on my fingers whenever I do this), but it is the only way to query across collections at the moment.

Comment: Thank you very much Frank! For others who got help with this question and its answer, please upvote them both.